# How can I pass one more argument to a Perl script?

Tags: perl

The *test_prop.pl* file currently accepts one argument:

```
my %options=();
getopts("i:", \%options);
$inputconf = $options{i};
```

This Perl script is getting called from a shell script as shown below:

```
perl test_prop.pl -i $FILE
```

I would like to pass one more argument to this perl script. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Where does the subroutine `getopts` come from? Are you using a CPAN module, or is it something the script implements itself?

Comment: If the perl script only takes one argument, what is the point of adding another? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: A standard  tool for processing command-line options in Perl is [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html).

Comment: The command `perl test_prop.pl -i $FILE` (assuming `$FILE` expands to a non-empty string with no whitespace) calls `perl` with 3 arguments.  What do you mean by "accepting one argument"?

Answer (score 2):

Following my template demonstrates how to handle multiple options, documenting the code for brief and full information.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# Description:
#   Describe purpose of the program
#
# Parameters:
#   Describe parameters purpose
#
# Date:     Tue Nov 29 1:18:00 UTC 2019
#
# Author:   Polar Bear 
#           https://stackoverflow.com/users/12313309/polar-bear
#

use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
use Pod::Usage;

my %opt;
my @args = (
            'input|i=s',
            'output|o=s',
            'debug|d',
            'help|?',
            'man|m'
        );

GetOptions( \%opt, @args ) or pod2usage(2);

print Dumper(\%opt) if $opt{debug};

pod2usage(1) if $opt{help};
pod2usage(-exitval => 0, -verbose => 2) if $opt{man};

pod2usage("$0: No files given.")  if ((@ARGV == 0) && (-t STDIN));

__END__

=head1 NAME

program - brief on program's purpose 

=head1 SYNOPSIS

 program.pl [options] file(s)

 Options:
    -i,--input  input filename
    -o,--output output filename
    -d,--debug  output debug information
    -?,--help   brief help message
    -m,--man    full documentation
    
=head1 OPTIONS

=over 4

=item B<-i,--input>

Input filename

=item B<-o,--output>

Output filename

=item B<-d,--debug>

Print debug information.

=item B<-?,--help>

Print a brief help message and exits.

=item B<--man>

Prints the manual page and exits.

=back

=head1 DESCRIPTION

B<This program> accepts B<input> and processes to B<output> with purpose of achiving some goal.

=head1 EXIT STATUS

The section describes B<EXIT STATUS> codes of the program

=head1 ENVIRONMENT

The section describes B<ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES> utilized in the program

=head1 FILES

The section describes B<FILES> which used for program's configuration

=head1 EXAMPLES

The section demonstrates some B<EXAMPLES> of the code

=head1 REPORTING BUGS

The section provides information how to report bugs

=head1 AUTHOR

The section describing author and his contanct information

=head1 ACKNOWLEDGMENT

The section to give credits people in some way related to the code

=head1 SEE ALSO

The section describing related information - reference to other programs, blogs, website, ...

=head1 HISTORY

The section gives historical information related to the code of the program

=head1 COPYRIGHT

Copyright information related to the code

=cut
```

Answer (score 2):

OP's post does not specify where `getopts()` is originated from

Let's assume `getopts()` originates from `Getopts::Std`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Getopt::Std;
use Data::Dumper;

$Getopt::Std::STANDARD_HELP_VERSION = 1;

my $version = '0.02';
my %opts;

getopts('iodn:',\%opts);

say 'INFO: -i input'            if $opts{i};
say 'INFO: -o output'           if $opts{o};
say "INFO: -n net $opts{n}"     if $opts{n};
say  Dumper(\%opts)             if $opts{d};

my $fname = shift;

say "INFO: filename $fname"     if $fname;

sub HELP_MESSAGE {
    say "
    This program performs specific task
    
    USAGE:
    program.pl [options] file(s)
    
    -i  input flag
    -o  output flag
    -n  dns network name
    -d  debug flag
    ";
}

sub VERSION_MESSAGE {

    say "
    program.pl  Vesion $version     2020
    ";
}
```

Run the program as `program.pl -i -o -0 something`

```
Unknown option: 0
INFO: -i input
INFO: -o output
INFO: filename something
```

Run the program as `program.pl -i -o -d something`

```
INFO: -i input
INFO: -o output
$VAR1 = {
          'd' => 1,
          'o' => 1,
          'i' => 1
        };

INFO: filename something
```

Run the program as `program.pl  -i -o -d -n something`

```
INFO: -i input
INFO: -o output
INFO: -n net something
$VAR1 = {
          'd' => 1,
          'i' => 1,
          'n' => 'something',
          'o' => 1
        };
```

Run the program as `program.pl --help`

```
        program.pl      Vesion 0.02             2020

        This program performs specific task

        USAGE:
        program.pl [options] file(s)

        -i      input flag
        -o      output flag
        -n      dns network name
        -d      debug flag
```

Run the program as `program.pl --version`

```
        program.pl      Vesion 0.02             2020
```

Documentation: [Getopts::Std](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Std)