# Parsing command line args, but not validating

Tags: perl

We have a module at work that is included in most scripts to create a logging event that includes who invoked the script and what command line args were passed to it.  Currently this simply uses a dump of @ARGV.

However, we're wanting to include this functionality for scripts that potentially include secure information that is passed on the command line.  We therefore still want to ledger the options passed to the script but masking the values.  `s/(?<=.{2})./X/sg`

For example

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump qw(dd);
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

local @ARGV = ( '-i', '--name' => 'value', '--password' => 'secure info', '--list' => 'foobar', '--list' => 'two' );

# The below GetOptions call specifics the allowed command line options
# to be parsed and validated.
#
# I want some way to accomplish the same but WITHOUT having to specify
# anything.
#
#  Something like: GetOptinos( \my %hash );   # Just do it without validation
GetOptions( \my %hash, 'i', 'name=s', 'password=s', 'list=s@' );

for ( values %hash ) {
    for ( ref($_) ? @$_ : $_ ) {
        s/(?<=.{2})./X/sg;
    }
}

dd \%hash;   # The the command line options are generically logged to a file with the values masked.
```

Outputs:

```
{
  i => 1,
  list => ["foXXXX", "twX"],
  name => "vaXXX",
  password => "seXXXXXXXXX",
}
```

The module I'm used to using for CLI parsing is [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long).

Is there a way to get [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long) to not validate, but simply generically parse the options into a hash without having to specify any of the allowed options?  Alternatively, is there another module that would give this ability?

Comment: How is `Getopt::Long` failing you exactly? (example..)

Comment: Please give a minimal, reproducible example and the congret error. Where is the parsing error.

Comment: @mpapec I gave an example to help explain my goal.

Comment: Please see following [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63837609/how-can-i-pass-one-more-argument-to-perl-script)

Comment: Cpan FTW :). `perl -MGetopt::Mini -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper \%ARGV' -- -i --name value --password secure info --list foobar --list two`

Comment: Re "*without having to specify any of the allowed options?*", No. In fact, it's more about specifying the type/number of values than what options are allowed. For example `--foo --bar --baz`  will be parsed very differently by `foo=s` than by `foo`

Comment: @ikegami Yes, that is true.  However, all I'm aiming for is a best guess.  This isn't meant for an exact interpretation of the command line args (which as you point out isn't possible), but the best effort so that I can attempt to mask the values for use in the logging events that are consumed by a public service, and therefore security is of issue.  Also, while your exceptions are valid, most of the scripts use relatively simple patterns for args, so I'm not expecting too much risk by this approach.

Comment: So you're saying you're ok with leaking passwords that start with `-`? Well, that's pretty easy `map { /^-/ ? $_ : obfuscate($_) } @ARGV`

Comment: I'm saying that @mpapec gave me an answer to my question and I appreciate it.  I also appreciate you pointing out the potential risks.  Will take that into account.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how `Getopt::Long` affects security, but I can think of a couple of ways to limit how much it works with provided arguments.

When a [user subroutine](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#User-defined-subroutines-to-handle-options) is used to process options

> It is up to the subroutine to store the value, or do whatever it thinks is appropriate.

I assume that the code just passes things to the sub. Then you can put them away as you wish

```
GetOptions(sensitive_opt => sub { $sensitive{$_[0]} = $_[1] }, ...) or usage();
```

Another way would be to not document the sensitive options for `Getopt::Long`, but provide the [argument callback `<>`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#Argument-callback), which runs for each unrecognized thing on the command line; then those can be processed by hand.  For this the [pass_through](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#pass_through-(default:-disabled)) configuration option need be enabled

```
use Getopt::Long qw(pass_through);  # pre 2.24 use Getopt::Long::Configure()

GetOptions(opt => \$normal_opt, ... '<>' => \&process_sensitive) ...
```

Then the given options are handled normally while the (expected) sensitive ones are processed by hand in `process_sensitive()`.

The drawback here is that the options unmentioned in `GetOptions` are literally untouched and passed to the sub as mere words, and one at a time. So there would be some work to do.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  In this case, pass_through isn't helpful since as you said it simply passes through the args one at a time untouched.  It doesn't do any of the work processing unrecognized args.  In this case all args are unrecognized by the generic module used for ledgering, so am leaning toward falling back on an imperfect regex: ```my @masked_argv = map {s/(?:\A-\S+=\K|(?!(?<=\A)-))./X/gr} @ARGV;
```

Comment: @Miller Right, with `pass_through` and `<>` you'd have to do _everything_ in the sub, starting with the re-assembly of those options, since it runs for each word separately. The one thing I liked about it is that it can be used for only the sensitive args while others are processed normally, and that it hides them fully (the `opt => sub {...}` approach doesn't quite).  This was simply the best I could think of with the good module (and before the code-example-clarification was added so I wasn't sure what exactly was needed).  Perhaps doing it all by hand is just better in this case.